# Google Apps Script regex parsing address: Unable to match embedded newline

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

Parsing PayPal emails to get the shipping address. Portion I am interested in is the shipping address:

```
Shipping address - confirmed
Mr Example
4692 E. Willow ave
Possible 2nd street address
My Nice City, CA 95337
United States
```

Working backwards from United States. This works:

```
// Returns "United States" as expected:
var matched = messageText.match(/United States/m)
```

As does this:

```
// Returns "\nUnited States" as expected:
var matched = messageText.match(/\nUnited States/m)
```

This pattern works for zip code:

```
// Returns "95337-4423" as well as "95337"
var matched = messageText.match(/\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?/m);
```

Working backwards to get both, this fails; no value of newline works for me:

```
var matched = messageText.match(/\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?\nUnited States/m)
```

Similar variations also fail:

```
var matched = messageText.match(/\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?[\s\S]United States/m)
var matched = messageText.match(/\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?[\r\n]United States/m)
```

What am I doing wrong to match a line preceded by another line?

Comment: What is that //`m` being used for? You may want to use `\r?\n` instead of just `\n`

Comment: Could be there's multiple white-space characters between the zip code and country (eg CR+LF). I'd go with `\s+United States`

Answer (score 1):

First matches okay:

```js
var messageText = "Shipping address - confirmed Mr Example 4692 E. Willow ave Possible 2nd street address My Nice City, CA 95337 United States";

var matched = messageText.match(/\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?[\s\S]United States/m);

console.log(matched);

var matched = messageText.match(/\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?[\r\n]United States/m);

console.log(matched);
```

You're better off going with `\s+United States` so as to include white space characters between code and country.

```js
var messageText = "Shipping address - confirmed Mr Example 4692 E. Willow ave Possible 2nd street address My Nice City, CA         95337 United States";

var matched = messageText.match(/\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?\s+United States/m);

console.log(matched);
```

Comment: `[\s+]` <- that's not how character classes work. Also, your `messageText` strings are missing the newlines from OP's question

Answer (score 1):

`/(.*(\s)){4}\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?[\s\S]?United States/m`

This part here `(.*(\s)){4}` It will grab any any character except new line and then any whitespace 4 times.  This captures the four lines above the zip code line that were being ignored by the code above.  If you want the text that says "Shipping address - confirmed" just change that 4 to a 5!

Hope this helps!

check it out here! http://regexr.com/3e4jt